# replace all img tags with alt in div innertHTML

Tags: javascript, replacewith

I have this code:

```
var str = document.getElementById('mesajyazi').innerHTML;
alert('input: '+str);

// first create an element and add the string as its HTML
var container = $('<div>').html(str);

// then use .replaceWith(function()) to modify the HTML structure
container.find('img').replaceWith(function() { return this.alt; })

// finally get the HTML back as string
var strAlt = container.html();
alert('output: '+strAlt);
```

It doesn't work.

But if I change var `str` to simple string text.

```
var str = 'This is a string with <img src="./images/logo.png" alt="logo" /> an image';
```

It works.

P.S. - inspired by this [Replace all <img> tag with img alt text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137107/replace-all-img-tag-with-img-alt-text) :)

Comment: What HTML code are you using?  It would be best to include a JSFiddle as well.

Comment: Well i just fixed the problem

here is http://jsfiddle.net/Zgn7m/

thanks for attention