# Angularjs replace image with it's alt

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an image like:

```
console.log( $scope.image ); // <img alt="hello" class="form" src="demo.jpg">
```

I want to have the following output (just the text of `alt`):

```
console.log( $scope.image ); // hello
```

There is an answer for jquery [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18137466/4055329). But I want to do the same in `Angularjs`. Any idea?

**Edit:** Also `$scope.image` contains more html.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do the same thing like in your posted answer with jquery using '[angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)' which give you access to several jquery functionalities set known as jqlite.

`var alt = angular.element($scope.image).attr('alt')`

**EDIT:** In case of more html tags inside your $scope.image, do this:

`var alt = angular.element($scope.image).find('img').attr('alt')`

Comment: Thanks. But I forgot to say, there is even more `html` beside `img` tag, and when we have more html, it doesn't work.

Comment: That's not a problem. Wrap all html into angular.element and then call .find('img'). This will give you access to img tag anyway, then call .attr('alt') like in my code example.

Comment: angular.element is jQlite if you don't include jQuery before your angular inclusion. That's why for example you can use .find() only with tag names and not selectors

Comment: Still getting the same error: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: aaaaaaa&nbsp;<img alt="" class="emojioneemoji" src="./emoji-cdn/2.1.4/assets/png/1f606.png">`